# OpenSSL Client/Server

Tags: c, security, networking, openssl, ssl

I have recently begun to dabble with OpenSSL to provide TLS encryption to TCP socket communication. Through documentation and heavy reference on example code I have come up with the following code (most of the code that is not related to OpenSSL has been gutted).

**Client**

```
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
#include <openssl/x509v3.h>

int create_socket(int port) {
  /* returns a valid socket fd */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int sock;
  SSL *ssl;
  SSL_CTX *ctx;
  const SSL_METHOD *method;
  X509_VERIFY_PARAM *param;

  /* init */
  SSL_load_error_strings();
  OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();

  /* create context */
  method = TLSv1_2_client_method();

  if (!(ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method))) {
    exit(1);
  }

  /* configure context */
  SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, NULL);
  SSL_CTX_set_verify_depth(ctx, 4);
  SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, "/path/to/cert.pem", NULL);
  SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION);

  /* open a socket */
  sock = create_socket(1337);

  /* create ssl instance from context */
  ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

  param = SSL_get0_param(ssl);

  X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set_hostflags(param, X509_CHECK_FLAG_NO_PARTIAL_WILDCARDS);
  X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host(param, "localhost", 0);

  /* assign socket to ssl intance */
  SSL_set_fd(ssl, sock);

  /* perform ssl handshake & connection */
  SSL_connect(ssl);

  /* perform ssl reads / writes */

  // SSL_read(ssl, buff, 255);

  /* cleanup */
  close(sock);
  SSL_free(ssl);
  SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
  EVP_cleanup();
}
```

**Server**

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                       
#include <unistd.h>                                                                                                                      
#include <sys/socket.h>                                                                                                                  
#include <arpa/inet.h>                                                                                                                   
#include <openssl/ssl.h>                                                                                                                 
#include <openssl/err.h>   
#include <openssl/x509v3.h>                                                                                                              

int create_socket(int port) {                                                                                                            
  /* returns a valid socket fd */                                                                                                        
}                                                                                                                                        

int main(int argc, char **argv) {                                                                                                        
  int sock;                                                                                                                              
  SSL_CTX *ctx;                                                                                                                          

  /* init */                                                                                                                             
  SSL_load_error_strings();                                                                                                              
  OpenSSL_add_ssl_algorithms();                                                                                                          

  /* create context */                                                                                                                   
  method = TLSv1_2_server_method();                                                                                                       

  if (!(ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method))) {                                                                                                    
    exit(1);                                                                                                                             
  }

  /* configure context */                                                                                                                
  SSL_CTX_set_ecdh_auto(ctx, 1);

  /* Set the key and cert */                                                                                                             
  if (SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ctx, "cert.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {                                                            
    exit(1);
  }

  if (SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "key.pem", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) <= 0) {                                                              
    exit(1);
  }                                                                                                                                      

  /* open a socket */
  sock = create_socket(5555);                                                                                                            

  /* Handle connections */                                                                                                               
  while(1) {                                                                                                                             
    int nsock;
    SSL *ssl;

    /* accept client connections
       if there are any */                                                                                                               
    nsock = accept_connection(sock);                                                                                                     

    /* create ssl instance from context */                                                                                               
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);

    /* assign socket to ssl intance */                                                                                                   
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, client);                                                                                                             

    /* perform ssl handshake & connection */                                                                                             
    SSL_accept(ssl);                                                                                                                     

    /* perform ssl reads / writes */
    SSL_write(ssl, buff, sizeof(buff));

    /* free ssl instance */
    SSL_free(ssl);

    /* close client connection */
    close(client);
  }
}
```

I would love feedback on the OpenSSL code. I would like to verify that this code is using modern OpenSSL programming techniques and function calls as it will serve as a reference foundation for further socket programming I would like to do. Like I said before, there is some code that has been removed for the sake of keeping the scope to OpenSSL (error output and formatting, the entire `create_socket` function, etc). Please let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: You don't document what the code actually should do outside of documenting each statement. So it is hard to tell if it is a correct implementation of what you aim for.  But, what is obvious for me is that you don't check that the target you access actually is the one you expect, i.e. that the hostname you want matches the subject of the certificate. This makes your code open to man in the middle attacks where the attacker just need to present an arbitrary certificate signed by the CA you trust. This might not be a problem if the CA is a single self-signed certificate only you have access to.

Comment: The goal of this code is to set up a secure connection between the client and the server. This functionality is all that I am aiming for with this implementation. As far as preventing man in the middle attacks, the function call *SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations* on the client specifies a directory and/or file to verify the certificate with. I have not been able to test with a certificate from a CA, but I have been able to test with a self-signed certificate by pointing that function to the actually certificate client side and it is approved. When pointed at a different file, it fails.

Comment: If you validate against a CA  you also need to check the subject so that you only accept the specific certificate matching the expected target and not an arbitrary certificate issued by the CA. See https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Hostname_validation.

Comment: The hard part of SSL is not to get an SSL connection working at all but to make sure that it is secure against man in the middle attacks. This means proper certificate validation and strong ciphers. You fail with the first since you don't check the subject of the certificate (and also don't check for revocation) and it is not clear if you succeed with the last. This probably depends on the version of OpenSSL and the ciphers declared as default. Also, you still allow TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 - it is recommended to use TLS 1.2 only if you control both client and server.

Comment: Which version of OpenSSL are you targetting? There are some differences between OpenSSL 1.0.2 and 1.1.0. If you are actually using 1.1.0 then you might do certain things differently.

Comment: How does code exit the `while(1) { ... }` loop to execute the following code?

Comment: Thank you @SteffenUllrich, that link is very helpful and clarifies a number of doubts I had on the code! I will also update the programs so that they only use TLS 1.2 as I fully intend to have control of both server and client.

Comment: @MattCaswell I will now only be working to use TLS 1.2, thank you for asking!

Comment: Currently it will never break out of the while loop, @chux, but there will be ways once the issues with OpenSSL are figured out!

Comment: Hmmm, I'd expect that [Your question must contain code that is already working correctly](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and so with an infinite loop 1) `close(sock);
  SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
  EVP_cleanup();` is not needed or 2) the code is not ready for review.

Comment: @chux I removed the unnecessary cleanup code at the end of the server program, so that should be in good shape, thank you!

Comment: I went ahead and changed the server and client methods to use TLS 1.2 only, and the client now implements functionality to properly check the certificate. What do you guys think? @SteffenUllrich?

Comment: Much better now. Still, you rely on OpenSSL setting strong enough ciphers for you which actually depends on the version of OpenSSL.  And there are still no revocation checks., i.e. neither CRL nor OCSP.